# How to extract delimited text to columns, excluding certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I've exported data from LiveEngage on customer service chat interactions and I'm trying to create a macro to help with a report I'm going to make on information provided such as NPS and delight with associate. After a customer finishes chatting with someone, they are prompted by the system to type in on a scale of 1-10 their satisfaction and to type any comments. That data is made into a column with the following format:
[NPS];[Resolution];[Delight with Associate];[Comments]

To complicate things, if the customer enters an invalid value (i.e. types text when it's wanting a number) it adds "InvalidAnswer" to that data. In some instances the customer closes the chat before it can collect all info so there are some rows with just single values. To show you what I mean here's some of the data:

```
InvalidAnswer;10;No;10;I want to chat again
InvalidAnswer;InvalidAnswer
9;Yes
10;Yes;10;Not today. Thanks
10;Yes;10
6
```

I'm trying to create a macro that will extract each of those elements into their own columns but not include InvalidAnswer. For instance, the data above would turn into.

```
NPS | Resolution | Delight | Comment
10    No           10        I want to chat again
9     Yes
10    Yes          10        Not today. Thanks
10    Yes          10
6
```

I greatly appreciate any input as I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Sub Delim()

Columns("A:H").Select
Selection.Replace What:="InvalidAnswer;", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=";InvalidAnswer", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="InvalidAnswer", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data is in a single column in Excel: if not, make it so

Data Tab: Text to Columns

Select Delimited then Next

Check Semicolon then next

Select Text then choose a Destination Cell then Finish

Home Tab: Format as table

Select Table then Replace "InvalidAnswer" with ""

If your looking for a macro for this try recording these steps, If that is still giving you trouble then post the code for the macro and explain the issue.

Hope this helps and please be kind and leave feedback.